# Torque at a bar

Tags: forces, momentum, torque

Take a look at the image below. At the point B a motor is spinning really fast in anticlockwise direction. The motor should be connected to a propeller (I didnt draw it) that will pull the bar upwards but let's suppose the propeller is not connected and the motor is just spinning really fast at X rpm.

A person is holding the bar at position A. What torque or force will the person at A feel? The bar has length L. I know if I connect the propeller the bar will be pulled upwards (you dont need to tell me about this) but I am pretty sure it's gonna generate a "reaction torque" in the bar that will be transmited to the person holding at A.

I would like to know the formula to understand the force/toque that A will feel.

[image]

Comment: You say the motor at point B is spinning "really fast". I am trying to visualize how that is consistent with a person holding the bar at A. Is the bar linked, or is the end of the bar touching a rapidly spinning disk at B? It changes the calculations a lot.

Comment: @Floris You have to read between the lines. The motor is hard-mounted to some rod (bar), and the rotating shaft of the motor is perpendicular to the bar.  The bar is not attached to the rotating shaft but to the housing of the motor.  If that's not what OP means, then the housing will rotate, but the analysis will be the same.

Comment: @BillN - I think I see it now. The word "housing" or "motor mount" would have helped me enormously. I can now appreciate your answer...

Comment: @BillN is correct, what he said is exactly what I need. The housing of the motor is connected to the bar not the axis.

Answer (score 1):

I will ignore torques produced by the gravitational field of the planet.

If the motor is currently spinning at constant angular speed, and the person is holding the system still, the torque the person at A experiences due to the rotation of the motor is zero because the angular momentum is constant.

If the person is holding at point A *before* the motor starts, the person will experience a torque when the motor starts and accelerates to some maximum angular speed. That torque will be the same magnitude as the torque on the propeller, and will be the time derivative of the instantaneous angular momentum:
$$\vec{\Gamma} = \frac{\mathrm{d}\vec{L}}{\mathrm{d}t}.$$

Comment: thank you you are correct! Indeed what you said is exactly what happens with a gyroscope. Good to know that. But Bill, if the motor has no propeller attached, and a person holds the bar and start spinning the motor I am really sure it will produce a reaction torque on the point A. Why does it happen even withouth propeller?

Comment: Because the shaft is changing angular momentum. That means there is a torque on the shaft. The conservation of angular momentum demands that the hand exerts a torque on the system to provide that angular momentum.